# change Date format in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to change the Date format in a asp grid displaying date format populated from Database.
The Database stores value in '2009-08-23 10:24:00.000' format but the value in grid is displayed as 'Sun 23-08-2009 10:24:00'
I want to display it as '23-AUG-2008'
VB .Net Code

```
"Dim dv As DataView1 = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView"
```

Markup is

```
<asp:BoundColumn    DataField="DateFormat"  HeaderText="Day&amp;Date">    
<ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
```

How can i display as '23-AUG-2008'?

Comment: Why do you not store your dates in a `DATETIME` column in the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "VB Script"? It is not the same as VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFormatString` property of the `BoundColumn`. There just specify the desired format.

In your case:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="DateFormat" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-YYYY}" HeaderText="Day&amp;Date">
```

Btw, `DataGridView` is a control from Winforms, not webforms...In webforms it's called `GridView`. And this has nothing to do with javascript or vb.net, so I've removed the tags as well.. The solution is specific to GridView control, which belongs to asp.net as whole no matter the code-behind language. Yes, you could use javascript to format those string, but...

Comment: @TimSchmelter, fixed that for you :)) Hope it's ok now.

Comment: I tried this , no luck
how about parsing each element in grid using javascript and change it

Comment: @SriCharan, what if the user's client doesn't support javascript? What if he has turned it off for security reasons? Not mentioning it's an unnecessary overhead and way more complicated than using built-in features of asp.net controls. What do you mean by "no luck"? What went wrong?